# Restrict other Admins from using Editor in Admin Panel

Tags: editor, user-roles, content-restriction

I am running a WordPress website. I want to assign other users roles like Admin, Editor, etc. I want them to be able to install plugins, themes, delete them, etc. The only thing I don't want them to do is access the "Editor" page. I don't want them to edit any core files directly , even if it is as small task as adding a CSS style. If they want to add anything, they will have to send those changes to me & I will upload those changes via FTP.

So how can I restrict other Admin, Editor, etc. completely from accessing the "Editor" while restricting access to it myself? If restricting access will cause a global lockout and will also lock me out if I try to restrict them, I am willing to go for this option too, if the former is not possible.

Can I achieve the above without using any plugin? If not, is there any plugin that will do the job for me?

I have access to WordPress core files, FTP, etc. I can make any modifications needed. So a solution in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admin and Super Admin roles are the only ones with access to edit themes. If you're wanting to give other people all other "Admin" capabilities but **not** access to edit themes, it'd probably be easiest to add the [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin, duplicate the Admin user with a new title and then just un-check the "edit_themes" capability for that role.

If you want to dig into the code a bit, you could use [the ultimate guide to roles and capabilities](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/) to hack together a solution.

I'd **strongly urge** you to NOT hack the WordPress core, as that leaves you SOL the next time they release a new version.

Comment: AWESOME! This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: no problem :) Glad I could help - and thanks for the 'accept' vote!